# How can I prevent error when I reset the Application?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm getting an error

`The value of the attribute datasource, which is currently '', is invalid.`

This happens when I call ApplicationStop() to reset the application. My cfquery calls doesn't have datasource property in it because I've already set it in

`this.datasource = "datasourcename"`

How can I prevent this error?

Update:

In a script based Application.cfc no error. The error only occurs on a tag based Application.cfc

if the query is in onRequestStart the error says
*Datasource database could not be found*

if the query is in onRequest the error says
*The value of the attribute datasource, which is currently '', is invalid.*

Server info:
local Env: CF11 - 
Production Env: CF 2018

Application.cfc code

```
<!--- Application name, should be unique --->
<cfset this.name = hash(getbaseTemplatePath())>
<cfset this.datasource = "database">


<!--- Run when application starts up --->
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onRequest" returnType="void">
    <cfargument name="thePage" type="string" required="true">


    <!--- RESET THE APP --->
    <cfif isdefined("url.reset" )>          
        <cfset ApplicationStop() > 
        <cfset structclear(session)>
        <cfhtmlhead text='<script type="text/javascript">alert("Application was refreshed.");</script>'>
    </cfif>

    <cfquery>
        select top 1 * from security_2fa
    </cfquery>

    <cfinclude template="#arguments.thePage#">
</cffunction>


<cffunction
        name="OnRequestStart"
        access="public"
        returntype="boolean"
        output="false"
        hint="Fires at first part of page processing.">



        <!--- Return out. --->
        <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: In what function do you set the datasource?

Comment: You are most likely calling `ApplicationStop()` too early in your request as it will terminate the application context immediately after being called, causing a `cfquery` to run with a now undefined datasource. (The application will not restart within the same request, but the next request.)

Comment: @DanBracuk I have a  cfquery in the onRequest function of Application.cfc. The cfquery doen't have datasource property because I've already set it in the this object. this.datasource = "db" when I reset the application by calling ApplicationStop(). It seems the this.datasource isn't set thus my cfquery call will throw an error.

Comment: @Alex yes on the next request the this.datasource will be set and the error will be gone. But the Application is not fully restarted when there is an error in ApplicationStart. I can wrap the cfquery with try/catch but I try to avoid the try/catch as much as I can and if I have 20 queries I will have to wrap them all with try/catch

Comment: So this is happening in your development environment and not your production environment, right?

Comment: Happens to both production and my dev environment.

Comment: @Vlad I've test your scenario in my local by using cf2018. I could not able to reproduce your mentioned issues. It's working fine. Do you have it any specific version ?

Comment: What happens if you move the query from the onRequest function to onRequestStart?

Comment: @DanBracuk
if the query is in onRequestStart
Datasource database could not be found

if the query is in onRequest
The value of the attribute datasource, which is currently '', is invalid.

Comment: @Kannan.P so far I've tried it in cf2018 and cf11 both error appers. In a script based Application.cfc the error is not encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Vlad Thank you for your code here. I've go through your code & it's help more to find an root causes of your issues. Yes I'm also facing the same issue by do test app in my local. The reason is you are did a **ApplicationStop()** in when your url have "**reset**". I don't know why you are stop your application here ? Usually we don't stop the any application. Instead we should reinit the application.

Here root cause of your issues is, if you did a **applicationStop()** then **this.name & this.datasource** also get **stopped or gone.**

```
<cfquery>
    select top 1 * from security_2fa
</cfquery>
```

So once it's stopped then in next line ( Above query ) you have query that don't have any data source name right ? Because it's already stopped or gone :).

```
<cfquery>
    select top 1 * from security_2fa
</cfquery>

<cfif isdefined("url.reset" )>          
    <cfset ApplicationStop() > 
    <cfset structclear(session)>
    <cfhtmlhead text='<script type="text/javascript">alert("Application was refreshed.");</script>'>
</cfif>
```

Now you never face the issue. Because your query get executed as before application stop. But you can **escape from this issue here only**. In case if your **arguments.thePage** having any other query then you should face the same issue there also. So if you want to stop the application for your scenario then you should do abort ( **cfabort** ) as soon as stop the application. Like below,

```
<cfif isdefined("url.reset" )>          
    <cfset ApplicationStop() > 
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Because if you stop the application then you don't want any action or operation or process on your apps.

I can give another suggestion for you, that is you no need to stop the application instead you can do a **reinit the application.** If you are using **fw1 or coldbox** or any other framework then use **fwreinit** option. But if you are working with normal MVC then use my below sample code

```
<cfif isdefined("url.reset" )>          
    <cfset onApplicationStart() > 
</cfif>
```

Hope it help you more. Let me know still need any help or clarifications. Thank you !.

Comment: I tried both ApplicationStop with cfabort and onApplicationStart(). Both works! Thank you. I learned something new again in controlling Application.cfc

I'm not using any framework.